# Rebinding Report to new XML XSD

Tags: c#, xml, crystal-reports, xsd, report

I cannot for the life of me find an example of what I need.

I have a report that is bound by **xsd**. How can I take this report in **c#**, and set the datasource to a new **xml** file? Every possible way that I've tried just throws me a nice logon screen. I know the files exists in the places that it is looking, and there is obviously no *username* and *password* to an **xml/xsd** file.

Anyone have any kind of advice on the subject? I dont understand why this isn't done more often and why no one can give me a straight answer. I can post some example code if anyone needs.

Comment: Can you post the code sample you mentioned?

Comment: Considering the date of the post, I think we should close this one.

Answer (score 1):

Reports based on XSD is for Design purpose only.

It is designed in this  way so that we can fill a dataset and do the databinding PUSH MODEL way.

There can be no login info for XSD as it neither is a datasource nor it has any authentication ability.

What you can send to a report is only limited by what can be put into a Dataset. You can fill the data from the XML into the Dataset and bind it to the report.